# How to get results in Views (Contextual Filters) regarded titles in URL in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-contextual-filters

I want Views to give me results by criteria of title of the node. I want to display all results from the nodes with the same title. So I used Pathauto module, and put what is in title fields into url. But when I tried to set contextual filters it doesn't return any results. I tried many options for example : 
Type -  Raw value from URL,
Path component: 1, 
and did some variation with that, but nothing. What I have to do.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use contextual filter, try this way:

1. Go to Advanced tab and turn "Use aggregation : Yes"
2. Add a filter Content: Title
3. Set Aggregation Type : Count
4. After that set Operator: Is greater than ; Value : 1